# Object doesn't get updated but gets added

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create a form that duplicates selected data and only one object can be edited with a `<b-form-select>`. All the data gets passed correctly but the problem is that instead of updating the id it gets added as a new object outside of the arrays.

this is what happens when I submit the form **:**

selected data:
`0:{ name:Green, audId: 11}, 1:{ name:Red, audId: 11},`

result: `0:{ name:Green, audId: 11}, 1:{ name:Red, audId: 11}, audId:13`

but it should be:`0:{ name:Green, audId: 13}, 1:{ name:Red, audId: 13},`

How do I get the audId inside to update. I would be grateful for any help :)

Script **:**

```
export default {
  props: {
    audiences: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
      default: null
    },
    selected: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedProp: {
        source: null,
        audId: null,
        name: '',
      },
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.selectedProp = { ...this.selected
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async submitForm($event) {
      console.log(this.selectedProp);

    },
  }
}
```

Template **:**

```
<template>
    <form @submit="submitForm($event)">
        <div>
            <label> Network </label>
                <b-form-select v-model="selectedProp.audId"> 
                  <option
                    v-for="audience in audiences"
                    :key="audience.id" 
                    :value="audience.id"
                  >
                    {{ audience.id }}
                  </option>
                </b-form-select>             
        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr v-for="(select, index) in selected" :key="index">
                        <th>Name<th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        {{ select.name }}
                        <input 
                          id="selectedProp.name"
                          v-model="selectedProp.name" 
                          class="form-control" 
                          type="hidden"
                          placeholder
                        >          
                      </td>
                    <tr>
                </tbody>
                <div> 
                  <b-button>Add</b-button>
                </div>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

Comment: Code looks incomplete to me and also not well organized. Can you please share a code snippet with the used methods.

Answer (score -2):

```
this.selectedProp = { ...this.selected};
// It should be written in the watch function


  watch: {
    selected: {
      handler(val) {
        if (val) {
          this.selectedProp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val)) // or cloneDeep
        }
      },
      immediate: true,
      deep: true,
    },
  },
```

I didn't see your $emit function
Can you post it?

Comment: Is this a solution? Or do you need more information to write the answer?

Comment: Yes, I need the $on $emit information of the component，To check whether your use is correct。